# Good Vim Blogs?

Tags: vim

I have used vim for near a one-year, but I think I have a great deal to learn. Does anyone know of any good blogs for vim?

EDIT: An example of what I mean with  `good` blogs is [Dialy Vim](http://dailyvim.blogspot.com). Actually I am looking for this kind of blogs that I could read in my Google Reader.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Good vim tutorial?](http://superuser.com/questions/16794/good-vim-tutorial)

Comment: no, it's not a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly subjective question the way you've phrased it; a "good" Vim blog will depend on the person. One such blog is the [Vim Tips Blog](http://www.zzapper.co.uk/vim-tips-blog/). However, if you want to truly master VIM, you will likely visit them all. In addition, the vim tutor program (tutor.vim) that comes with most VIM installs is a good place to start, although I imagine you are already beyond what it has to offer.

I learned by reading [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/) and I carried the [Vi Editor Pocket Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565924975) in my pocket to read when stuck on the bus.

I realize only my first suggestion is a blog; I am guessing you are really just looking for good resources. You may want to rephrase the question, and give details as to what resources you have found that are not meeting your needs.